# js split by new line (\n) got unexpected token?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

says I have a long list of item

```
a
b
c
```

I want to quickly split them into array, I did

```
"a
b
c".split('\n')
```

but I got `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`

what's the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating multiline strings in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805107/creating-multiline-strings-in-javascript)

Comment: The split string should be  `'\n'` and not `'/n'`

Comment: @Willian fixed that, still doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean a long list of item?

Comment: Invalid syntax is invalid. It is failing to parse, and `split` is never called.

Comment: I mean, it should be like this: `a
b
c\`.split('\n')

Answer (score 5):

Use [backtick](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) instead

```
`a
b
c`.split('\n')
```

Output

```
[
  "a",
  "b",
  "c"
]
```

Answer (score -1):

The code below is my best take, without using the \n operator (there is a much easier way to do a line break in JS) in JavaScript, using a little HTML, using the HTML line break operator. This is my code:

```
var list = ["a", "b", "c"];
var lineBreak = "<br/>";
document.write(list[0]+lineBreak+list[1]+lineBreak+list[2]);
```

Is that good enough? Let me know.